# Cannot call service: "'MyPlugin' not found" error

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I'm sure this is a trivial mistake but I can't figure it out (first-time plugin dev).

I have my plugin running with all code in the controller and want now follow best practice and move the workhorse code into a service class.

My main plugin code is

```
namespace ns\yutulic;
use ns\yutulic\models\SettingsModel;
use craft\models\Section;

public function init() {

    parent::init();

    self::$plugin = $this;

    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    $settings->sectionOptions = $this->setSectionOptions();

    // Register services
    $this->setComponents([
        'videoentries' => \ns\yutulic\services\VideoEntriesService::class,
    ]);

    $data = $this->videoentries->scanForVideos(null); // works

}
```

The relevant controller code is

```
Class ScanController extends Controller {
    public function actionScanEntries() {
        // Neiter works :-(
        //$data = Yutulic::$plugin->videoentries->scanForVideos($id);
        $data = Yutulic::getInstance()->videoentries->scanForVideos($id); // (*)
    }
}
```

And my service code:

```
<?php
namespace ns\yutulic\services;
use ns\yutulic\Yutulic;
use Craft;
use craft\base\Component;

class VideoEntriesService extends Component
{
    public function scanForVideos($sectionId = null) {
        echo "Works!!!";
        return null;
    }
}
```

Even if I use the [example of the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/services.html#creating-a-service) it fails with the same error message on the line indicated (*) in the controller (but with the 'Foo' class name):

```
Class 'ns\yutulic\Yutulic' not found
```

This shouldn't be so hard?

Comment: What's the name and class of your main plugin file?

Comment: @RoussKS That was indeed the problem (see my answer below). I had copied code from an example that was different from all other plugins I reviewed. Eventually it dawned on me that the class name was wrong.

Comment: It was an instant thought (even though simplistic. Happens to the best of us :) glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The author of the tutorial I copied my first code from made the unfortunate choice to not use a proper plugin class:

```
class Plugin extends \craft\base\Plugin { ... }
```

To fix the problem, I replaced this line with

```
use Craft;
use craft\base\Plugin;
class Yutulic extends Plugin { ... }
```

and had to add a reference to the class to my controller and service modules:

```
use ns\yutulic\Yutulic;
```